# Comprimir una carpeta de google Colab para descargar

Tags: zip, google-colab, download

Solicito su ayuda, estoy utilizando un cuaderno de google colab en el cual necesito descargar cerca de 27.000 imágenes, el problema es que la única solución es comprimir la carpeta para luego descargar
ya que el codigo que tengo:

```
    for i in os.listdir('/content/Real-ESRGAN/results') :  
 #print(i)
 files.download('/content/Real-ESRGAN/results/'+i)
```

Realiza las descarga pero de forma individual y por ende al ser muchas imágenes el navegador colapsa.

[image: EJEMPLO]

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré la solución por si alguien mas la necesita. El código es el siguiente:

Subir archivo zip para descomprimir

1. Subir archivo zip a una ruta de google colab , primero deben subir su zip a su gdrive y montar la unidad para luego descomprimir en la carpeta de destino.

Subir Zip Y descomprimir en carpeta X:

```
!unzip "/content/drive/MyDrive/yourfolder/frames.zip" -d "/content/destino/upload/"
```

2. Comprimir una carpeta en google colab para descargar

Comprimir

```
!zip -r "/content/yourfolder/results/frames.zip" "/content/yourfolder/results"
```

Descarga:

```
from google.colab import files
files.download("/content/yourfolder/results/frames.zip")
```

Answer (score 0):

con la librería 'shutil' podrías comprimirla también. usando el método make_archive().

```
import shutil
archivo = shutil.make_archive('nombre_archivo_zip', 'zip','path_de_fichero')
```

te crea un archivo zip (o tar si quieres, hay que cambiar 'zip' por 'tar') que luego lo descargas y listo.